# Custom validation in CoreUI form is not working

Tags: reactjs, forms, validation, bootstrap-modal, core-ui

I am trying to add custom validation to my form on modal using coreui react but not able to get it to work. Getting below error

Property 'noValidate' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & CFormProps & RefAttributes'

```
     <CModal    
    <CForm noValidate validated={validated} onSubmit={handleAddFormSubmit} className="row">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-12" style={{ paddingLeft: '25px' }}>
          <CFormInput
            className="mb-2"
            type="text"
            name="Username"
            placeholder="Enter UserName..."
            value={formData.UserName}
            onChange={handleAddFormChange}
            maxLength={2}
            required 
          />
          <CFormFeedback invalid>Please choose a username.</CFormFeedback>              
          <div />
       </div>
       </CForm>
  </CModal>
```

Tried Below way too- getting below errors

Property 'noValidate' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & CFormProps & RefAttributes'
Property 'feedbackInvalid' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & CFormProps & RefAttributes'

```
<CModal    
<CForm noValidate validated={validated} onSubmit={handleAddFormSubmit} className="row">
  <div className="row">
    <div className="col-12" style={{ paddingLeft: '25px' }}>
      <CFormInput
        className="mb-2"
        type="text"
        name="Username"
        placeholder="Enter UserName..."
        value={formData.UserName}
        onChange={handleAddFormChange}
        maxLength={2}
        required 
        feedbackInvalid="Please provide a valid user name."
      />             
      <div />
   </div>
   </CForm>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, you are still using coreUi V3.**.
Update the version of coreUi to 4.1.5 or higher.
Please read the migration guide from V3 to V4 here [https://coreui.io/docs/migration](https://coreui.io/docs/migration/)/

It works fine in the latest version.